# How can I recive a response data from an http request in Angular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, httprequest

I want to read a response from a get http request, my server is in Javascript and the part of the where I send a response is:

```
app.get('/getReport',function(req,res) {
  try {
    const data=fs.readFileSync('./report.txt', 'utf8')
    res.end(data)
  }
  catch (err) {
    res.end("File not found")
  }
})
```

If if I use Postman I can see the content of the report file.
I want to read this text on my Angular front-end so I create this function in my home.service.ts:

```
   public getReport(){
   return this.http.get<any>(this.url+'/getReport').subscribe(data => {
    this.value = data;})        
  }
```

It doesn't work. what can I do to read my content correctly?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: That it does not do anything, I can't read any text, it is enpty

Comment: You see, things rarely just "don't work". There probably is some error message, some unexpected value, some failed connection. Please investigate further the error itself, present it to us, and we will try to help to fix it

Comment: There isn't any error it just does not read the html response that I can read with the Postman's query URL

Comment: "It" and "read" are too ambiguous. Sorry, can't help

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway I hope someone else can do it

Answer (score 0):

Check your [setup](https://angular.io/guide/http#setup-for-server-communication). You have to import some modules before get http requests:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // import HttpClientModule after BrowserModule.
    HttpClientModule,
  ],...
```

Comment: I already had it import in the same way and also already do a post and get request in my home.service.ts and they works perfectly, so I think the problem is this get in particular.

Answer (score 0):

In order to recive any response, you have to **start a communication with your API/server subscribing to the 'getReport' method**.

**HOW CAN YOU DO THAT?**

You have that method in your *home.service.ts*.

1. **Inject that service** in the component where you want to load your report (i.e 'home-component'):

```
// NOTE: Fit all the paths to your specific system
...
import { HomeService } from '../services/home.service';
...

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-component',
  templateUrl: './home-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-component.scss'],
})
export class HomeComponent {

public report;

 constructor(
...
    private homeService: HomeService,
...

  ) {}
```

2. **Subscribe to the observable 'getReport' method** of homeService, and get the desired data.
   For instance, change the constructor like this:

```
 constructor(
...
    private homeService: HomeService,
...

  ) {

       this.homeService.getReport
        .subscribe((_response) => {
           console.log(_response);
           this.report = _response;
           alert(this.report);
       });

}
```

Comment: I already done all this thinks except the .subscribe on my home.component method instead of on my home.service method. so write this :
`async openReport(){
   this.homeservice.getReport().subscribe((_report) => {this.report = _report;})
    alert(this.report)

  }` but it does not work because the alert print me : undefind. And I also write report in this way `public report: any;` because without :any it gives me an error.

Comment: Don't mix 'observable subscribes' and 'async/awaits'... Try to do it in the simple way of my answer.I have added the alarm in the right place. If your back/API works fine and it's properly programmed, it's going to work! You'll see! :)

Comment: Now it doesn't give me any alert

Comment: What does the "console.log" show in console ?

Comment: which console should i watch? The one where I write 'ng serve'?

Comment: No, the browser console.